# Can you curry a function that has only one parameter that is an object

Tags: javascript, currying

Here is an example of currying the calculation of the volume of a rectangular prism. This is textbook curry.

```
function volume(l, w, h) {
    return l * w * h;
}

function curriedVolume(length) {
    return function(width) {
        return function(height) {
            return height * width * length;
        }
    }
}

volume(2, 3, 4); // 24
curriedVolume(2)(3)(4); // 24
```

Here is a similar example except the non-curried function takes one parameter which is an object.

```
function volume(dimensions) {
    return dimensions.l * dimensions.w * dimensions.h;
}

function curriedVolume(dimension, finalDimensions={}) {
    Object.assign(finalDimensions, dimension);
    if (Object.keys(finalDimensions).length === 3) {
        return finalDimensions.l * finalDimensions.w * finalDimensions.h;
    }
    return function(dimension) {
        return curriedVolume(dimension, finalDimensions);
    }
}

volume({
    l: 2,
    w: 3,
    h: 4,
});
curriedVolume({ l: 2 })({ w: 3 })({ h: 4 }); // 24
curriedVolume({ w: 2, h: 3 })({ l: 4 }); // 24
```

Is this still considered "currying?" Is it valid?

Comment: I've often wondered the same thing, but to be honest I think it depends on how strict you are with your definition of currying. That makes this question somewhat opinion based, so watch out for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've commented that this question is somewhat a matter of opinion, but I'm intrigued enough to offer my perspective, despite feeling somewhat naughty. I haven't provided a definitive answer (because I'm not sure that one exists), but I'm going to assert by investigation that your second example is not currying as is usually meant by the term.

Your example will partially apply the parameters until it has closed over enough of them to calculate the result, whereupon it will return the calculated volume. That's not up for debate.

To claim that it is an example of currying, you would have to argue that:

1. The outer function takes three arguments, they just happen to be hidden inside an object parameter, and then that
2. Each partially applied function that is returned declares a single object parameter

Both of those claims must be true for your example to fit the definition of currying.

However, now you're in a contradiction. By 1) an object argument is not "really" a singular parameter. But then in 2), you must directly contradict 1) in order to make the claim that the returned functions are functions of only one argument. So there's that inconsistency.

Semantics aside, passing a single object as an argument changes the calling mechanics of the curried function such that you can call it with an object that contains all three pseudo-arguments (object properties) if you happen to have them, in which case you won't get a function value returned - instead you'll get the calculated volume right away. That makes the function not trivially re-entrant. Imagine you are passing objects to this function that are the result of some data-stream. Now your function behaves differently with the exact same line of code, depending on the state of the object you give it. Again arguably, this does not obey the "spirit of the law" when it comes to currying because you have introduced a side effect to the function that makes it hard to reason about the behaviour of your code.

Finally, and probably most importantly, by writing a function that receives an object as an argument, you have erased the type signature of your function so that nothing can be inferred from it without reading the internal code itself. This will make it impossible to use in a meta-programming approach because it will share the same type signature as a function that expects an object with two properties, or four, or ten.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an object in a function is still currying.

[image]

See [this quote](https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e):

> Named after Haskell Brooks Curry, currying is the process of breaking down a function into a series of functions that each takes a single argument...

And from [here](https://codeburst.io/currying-in-javascript-ba51eb9778dc):

> Currying is a technique of evaluating function with multiple arguments, into sequence of function with single argument.

So as long as you don't have two arguments in your function, then yes, it is still considered "currying".

Comment: But from your second quote, my function does not have multiple arguments - it has one.

Comment: @Ogen No, it's just generic currying practice - `function Foobar(foo, bar)` turns into `function Foobar(foo) { function Bar (bar) } `.